# Override IsLockedOutAsync on Asp.Net Identity UserManager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I need to override IsLockedOutAsync on my Asp.Net Identity UserManager.  I am building a multi-tenant application in which I identify the tenant by using the request URL [tenant].myapp.com.  The logic for whether or not a user is locked out needs to know who the tenant is.

The problem is, with the override IsLockedOutAsync method (and any of the UserManager or SignInManager overrides for that matter) **being async** , I've found that I don't have access to HttpContext.Current - it returns null.  This is, of course, catastrophic for my application!  No http context means no url, which means no way to identify the tenant.

Please could someone advise as to how I can resolve the tenant when overriding these async methods?  I've read other suggestions of passing the required properties from the httpcontext to the async method before going async, but in these cases, I don't control the process of going async.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this: use middleware. I'm not sure if the following code 100% good. But you can see how it is done.

Startup Class:

```
public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseTenantResolver();
}



using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;

namespace Multitenant
{
    public static class TenantResolverMiddlewareAppBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static void UseTenantResolver(this IApplicationBuilder builder) 
        {
            builder.UseMiddleware<TenantResolverMiddleware>();
        }
    }
}


namespace Multitenant
{
public class TenantResolverMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public TenantResolverMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<TenantResolverMiddleware>();
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        using (_logger.BeginScope("TenantResolverMiddleware"))
        {
            var tenant = new Tenant
            {
                Id = "tenant1" // todo: determine this based on HttpContext etc.
            };

            _logger.LogInformation(string.Format("Resolved tenant. Current tenant: {0}", tenant.Id));

            var tenantFeature = new TenantFeature(tenant);
            context.Features.Set<ITenantFeature>(tenantFeature);

            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}
}
```